# Excel VBA: Cell color change on double click

Tags: excel, colors, onclick, cell

Below you can find code which switch cell color on double click,  I need to make it to work only for the cells in the range D2:D14. Currently this applies to all cells..

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, cancel As Boolean)
cancel = True
Select Case Target.Interior.ColorIndex
    Case xlNone, 4: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Case xlNone, 6: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Case Else: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
End Select
End Sub
```

Please help me! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Intersect`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Intersect(Target, Range("D2:D14")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Cancel = True

Select Case Target.Interior.ColorIndex
    Case xlNone, 4: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Case xlNone, 6: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Case Else: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple Answer to toggle:

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Cancel = True

Target.Interior.Color = IIf(Target.Interior.Color = vbWhite, vbGreen, vbWhite)

End Sub